# Where can I find replacements for Oxberg door hinges with a damper?

Tags: safety, hinges, ikea

I have Ikea Oxberg hinges that my 2yo is slamming heavily. I wonder if there is a replacement that can have a damper? Ikea does not provide such, so maybe anyone knows a replacement?

[image: oxberg hinges]

Comment: IKEA has hinges with dampers.  Idk if they will fit your cabinet.  Take a hinge to the parts desk at IKEA and talk to them.  Midweek early in the morning obviously.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it's a shopping question asking  for help buying a specific product.

Comment: @jay613, there's a "product/shopping" close option that doesn't require all that extra typing. :)

Comment: Stack Exchange / Parenting may be able to give you a non-hardware approach to solving the problem. https://parenting.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think my parents would have prefer the slamming doors to me sticking things into outlets.

Comment: Hit a woodworking store, tell them that you want a damped "euro" hinge (that's  the general class of hinges which install into a 35mm pocket in the door), bring in one of the existing hinges so they can see exactly which variety it is (overlay or inset, how wide it swings...) and they should be able to match it or tell you what you need to order.

Answer (score 2):

Most hinges that have dampers will dampen when the door is closing naturally, not when being slammed. You can check the hinges yourself at Ikea or at your home store for the proper one and it's ability to dampen when being slammed. Home stores usually have a large selection and have some mounted on sample doors so you can see for yourself.

An easier solution might be to get some cabinet door bumpers like the ones shown below from Home Depot. They just stick on the door and come in a variety of colors.

[image]

Comment: Home stores (at least those around me) don't have _that_ much in the way of hinge selection. However, wood worker's stores _do_. I will note, though, that IKEA seem to have slightly proprietary hinge designs that make finding a "universal" replacement from somewhere _other_ than IKEA more difficult.

Comment: I'd be surprised if Ikea wasn't using standard Euro hinges, though they may be uncommon versions thereof.